# Regular HTML pages on Struts 2 Spring Framework

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, tomcat, struts2

I personally do not have much experience working in jsp and struts2 tomcat server but I have a small task that I have to deal with a server in production. I looked at info on the internet for two nights but seems like i can't get the answer.

What I want to do is to open some static simple html pages pop-up from the jsp pages that already exist.  Those jsp pages are currently located at /webapps/WEB-INF/tld/mainPage/indexMainPage.jsp

what I did was:

make some javascript functions so that when they click a button, i open a pop-up

```
function btn_openPopUp()
 {
    window.open("../popUp/test.html");
 }
```

and put the test.html page at /webapps/WEB-INF/tld/popUp/test.html

The pop-up part works fine as it is just simplye javascript, but test.html is not displayed.

```
Struts Problem Report

Struts has detected an unhandled exception:

Messages:   
There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name test.
```

I have been looking at info online, and everything about struts is action based.  Is there anyway I can open a page like on a regular server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pages under WEB-INF are not directly accessible to clients; put such pages under the root somewhere.

They can still be in sub-directories if it makes sense, just not under WEB-INF. If they *must* be under WEB-INF for some reason (which makes no sense for non-JSP pages) they can be streamed through an action like any other file--bit that'd be weird for HTML pages.

Comment: he should get 404 error instead he was getting unexpected error why?

Comment: @MohanaRaoSV Depends on his web.xml and S2 config.

Comment: <filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

Comment: @MohanaRaoSV That's configuration; it doesn't explain what your point is.

Comment: I thought you would understand my doubt. Consider above configuration So now /popUp/test.html passes through the Struts filter. But i'm not getting action not found exception.(possible scenario of getting action not found exception).

Comment: @MohanaRaoSV Also depends on your S2 config.

Comment: thanks for all you answers/comments.  However, what should the relative url be if i put the htmls under webapps.  ../../popUp/test.html?

Comment: @AbSoLution8 IMO you should not use a relative URL.